# OpenXML: How to copy a worksheet to another workbook?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I need to merge the worksheets of some workbooks into one new workbook. What I tried is this, but I am getting "Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree.".

```
using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destinationFileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    // Add a WorkbookPart to the document
    var workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart
    var worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

    foreach (var sourceFileName in sourceFileNames)
    {
        using (var sourceDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(sourceFileName, false))
        {
            var sheet = (Sheet)sourceDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.FirstChild;
            workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Worksheet(sheet));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that you are trying to add an `OpenXmlElement` (a `Sheet` in this case) that already has a parent `OpenXmlCompositeElement` (a `Sheets` object in this case) as a new child to another `OpenXmlCompositeElement` (a `Worksheet` in this case).

In the following line item, you are grabbing a reference to a `Sheet` object that already has a parent `Sheets` object.

```cs
var sheet = (Sheet)sourceDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.FirstChild;
```

With `new Worksheet(sheet)`, you are trying to add that same `sheet` to another parent, i.e., the `Worksheet` instance that you are creating. That does not work.

Assuming for a moment that it makes sense to add a `Sheet` to a `Worksheet`, your second line would have to be rewritten as follows:

```
workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Worksheet(sheet.CloneNode(true)));
```

In the above line of code, `sheet` is replaced with `sheet.CloneNode(true)`, which makes a deep copy of your original `Sheet` object that does not have a parent. Thus, the clone can be added as a new child to another parent.

While the above solution is an answer to your immediate question (because it avoids the error message), your code does not make sense, because it does not create valid Open XML markup. `Worksheet` instances should not be added to `Workbook` instances, and `Sheet` instances should not be added to `Worksheet` instances. This is not how you would copy multiple worksheets, which is a very complicated task that requires you to create multiple worksheet parts, link those worksheet parts to your workbook part, and consider shared strings, styles, and other things.

Comment: any code snippet to copy sheet from one workbook to another using open xml?